# button events in dynamic ListAcitvity android

Tags: android, listactivity, togglebutton

Hi I have generated a dynamic list. I have SeekBar and a ToggleButton for each of the rows in List. I have been trying to generate events for the toggle and seek from the last 1 week but in vain. Please help me with it.

Here is the XML code with the List(smartunits.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/unitsLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/grid_gradient"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now the code for each row(listunits.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/unitName"
        android:layout_width="40px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="20px"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/unitCodeId"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/unitsseek"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggle"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/off_grey"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn="" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code for ListActivity

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class UnitsListActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // put the bottom code here

        setContentView(R.layout.smartunits);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        final AutomationDBAccessor db = new AutomationDBAccessor(this);
        Cursor cUnits = db.getUnits(extras.getInt("roomFloorId"), extras.getInt("roomId"));

        String[] from = new String[] { AutomationDBAccessor.colUnitName, AutomationDBAccessor.colUnitCodeID };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.unitName, R.id.unitCodeId };
        SimpleCursorAdapter sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listunits, cUnits, from, to);

        this.setListAdapter(sca);

        View viewUnits = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.listunits, null);
        final ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) viewUnits.findViewById(R.id.toggle);

        toggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (toggle.isChecked()) {

                    toggle.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.on));
                } else {
                    toggle.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.off_grey));

                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now I am unable to handle the ToggleButton events.

Comment: You'll have to implement your own `SimpleCursorAdapter` and in the `bindView()` method set the listeners for those views but also set a way for the listeners to know which `ToggleButton` and SeekBar` the user acted on.

Comment: Try deleting `viewUnits` in `final ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) viewUnits.findViewById(R.id.toggle);
` . Another suggestion would be to just build a toast to see if it just works. If the toast works, then something might be wrong with `toggle.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.foo));` methods that you're using. When you say you're unable to handle `ToggleButton` events, try mentioning what exactly is happening. Like crashes or no result at all. Some info of that sort would help.

Answer (score 0):

I never try this, But you can do something like,

In your **listunits.xml**

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggle"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textOff=""
    android:textOn=""
    android:onClick="toggleButtonClick" />
```

And in your **UnitsListActivity**

write this method..

```
public void toggleButtonClick(View view)
{   
    ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) view;

    if (toggle.isChecked()) {
        toggle.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.on));
    } else {
        toggle.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.off_grey));
    }
}
```

Run this code and let me know what happen..

Comment: I may be wrong on this, But Theoretically I think it should work..!

Comment: @Ghost viewUnits is mandatory as the toggle is in the listunits and not smartunits. The activity is currently working with the smartunits.

Comment: I have just tried with it and it is not working. I have also tried with a toast(for toggleButtonClick), but it is not displaying any text.

Comment: Just put debugger point at the method toggleButtonClick and check whether execution come to in this method.

Comment: I am unable to track the problem with the debugger.